# Is it sensible to generate aggregation layer with Activiti in Micro Service

Tags: java, microservices, activiti, bpmn

My project is created with Micro Service architecture, one business process may need multiple services call. I want to use Activiti to generate aggregation layer, so that dev can write less code and we can just deploy different bpmn file if the workflow changed. Is it sensible? Anybody has the similar experience?

Answer (score 3):

Totally, have you looked at activiti cloud? That is the whole purpose of the project

Comment: Do you mean activiti cloud is designed to generate the aggregation layer?

Comment: thanks for your kindly reply. One more question, is it also support using with spring mvc project? All of the services are atomized, just use activiti to generate invoke chain. I haven't using activiti before, so I don't know if the performance is qualified to high concurrency.

Comment: Activiti Cloud is designed to provide you with that layer and enable your services integrations. Regarding concurrency, it really depends on your requirements. Are you using a message broker already? Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: thanks! If I use Activiti 6.x to generate my aggregation layer with spring mvc project, is it sensible? All of the services are atomized, just use activiti to generate invoke chain.